# trigger SearchView of xml layout and get the text

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I dont know whether i can do like this or not

I have added a  Sherlock.widget.SearchView to my xml layout

```
    <com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp" >
    </com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView>
```

then m getting xml layouts id to my activiy

```
    etSearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
         etSearch.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
```

now i want to trigger searchview and get the text entered from searcbar and pass it to another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must implement the [OnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) interface:

//YourActivity

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Called when the user submits the query
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("query", query);
            YourActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
 };

 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

//NextActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("query");
}
```